# Junction object affecting security using community

Tags: community

We are trying to design a solution where we might want to use a junction object to create a many to many relationship.

Someone mentioned that if one uses a junction object than it adversly affects controlling sf security in a community which we also wish to implement.

Is this true? Anyone have info on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A junction object is just a normal object, so you'll have the same security implications that you have with a normal object IMHO.

Comment: Ok. What I am hearing that there is no known negative implications. ty.